# How to fix: Calling a node by name (generated by func) won't work

Tags: swift

I'm currently working on my first test game in which the player have to jump over some randomly generated bars.
I wrote a func which should generate the bars outside of my scene. 
My problem at the moment is that when I'm trying to call the created bars with "self.childNode(withName:)" xCode is telling me "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I've already read the Apple Documentation for "childNode(withName:)" and added "//" before the name of the node. In addition I used the stackoverflow search but I can't find anything that solved my problem.

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  PlaxerJump
//
//

import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let bottom1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom")
    let bottom2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bottom")
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")

    var velocity = CGFloat(0)
    var onGround = true

    var value = CGFloat(5)

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // Hintergrund
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.lightGray
        bottom1.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        bottom1.position = CGPoint.zero
        bottom1.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(bottom1)

        bottom2.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        bottom2.position = CGPoint(x: bottom1.size.width - 1, y: 0)
        bottom2.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(bottom2)

        // Spieler
        player.position = CGPoint(x: player.size.width / 2 + 20, y: bottom1.size.height + player.size.height / 2)
        player.zPosition = 2
        self.addChild(player)

        //Balken
        addBalken(xScale: 1.5, yScale: 1, name: "ba1", xPoint: 0)


    }


    func addBalken(xScale: CGFloat, yScale: CGFloat, name: String, xPoint: CGFloat) {
        let balken = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Balken")
        balken.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        balken.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width + (2 * balken.size.width) + xPoint, y: bottom1.size.height - 16)
        balken.zPosition = 1
        balken.xScale = xScale
        balken.yScale = yScale
        balken.name = name
    addChild(balken)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if onGround == true {
            velocity = -16
            onGround = false
            self.run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Jump.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
        }

    }



    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        //Player
        player.zRotation -= CGFloat(Double.pi * 5) / 180

        velocity += 0.6
        player.position.y -= velocity


        if player.position.y <= bottom1.size.height {
            player.position.y = bottom1.size.height
            velocity = 0
            onGround = true
        }

       //Bottom
        bottom1.position.x -= 4
        bottom2.position.x -= 4
        if bottom1.position.x < -bottom1.size.width {
            bottom1.position.x = bottom2.position.x + bottom2.size.width
        } else if bottom2.position.x < -bottom2.size.width {
           bottom2.position.x = bottom1.position.x + bottom1.size.width
        }

        //Balken - ** THIS IS THE PART WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS **
        let balke1 = self.childNode(withName: "//ba1") as! SKSpriteNode
        balke1.position.x -= value

        if balke1.position.x < self.size.width {
            balke1.position.x = self.size.width + (2 * balke1.size.width)
            value = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(value)))

        }


    }


}
```

I just want to call the node so I can use it to implement the bars in the game.

Comment: Does it work to remove the `//` from the name for both when you create the node and when you are retrieving the node?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately that didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
addBalken(xScale: 1.5, yScale: 1, name: "//ba1", xPoint: 0)
```

to:

```
addBalken(xScale: 1.5, yScale: 1, name: "ba1", xPoint: 0)
```

The `//` only applies when searching for the node, so keep these characters in this line:

```
let balke1 = self.childNode(withName: "//ba1") as! SKSpriteNode
```

EDIT:

I think the root cause of your problem is that you forgot to call `addChild` in your `addBalken` function. Simply creating a node isn't enough. The node must also be added to the scene as well. So this is the final code:

```
func addBalken(xScale: CGFloat, yScale: CGFloat, name: String, xPoint: CGFloat) {
    let balken = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Balken")
    balken.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
    balken.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width + (2 * balken.size.width) + xPoint, y: bottom1.size.height - 16)
    balken.zPosition = 1
    balken.xScale = xScale
    balken.yScale = yScale
    balken.name = name

    //add the node to the scene
    addChild(balken)
}
```

Comment: I already changed that, the // are only leftovers... Even with your suggested changes I get the same Error.

Comment: What do you mean by "leftovers"?

Comment: I tried to solve the problem myself and after that I forgot to delete the // in the function name before posting the code...

Comment: @whyowhy I have edited the answer. It should work now after you make these edits.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. That makes totally sense. I added your suggestions, but I get the same error still... Now I'm very confused. But I added your suggestions to my original Post.